# Allign a child submenu to the top of the parent menu

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I want to align horizontal a child ul sub-menu with the parent menu using only css and html.

HTML:

```
    <ul>
       <li><a href"#">Item 1</a>
       <ul>
          <li><a href"page1.html">Item 1 child 1</a></li>
          <li><a href"page2.html">Item 1 child 2</a></li>
          <li><a href"#">Item 1 child 3</a></li>
       </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href"page3.html">Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href"page4.html">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
    li{
      list-style: none;
      height:22px;
      font-size: 13px;
      background:#eee;
      width:110px;
    }

    li ul{
      margin-left:100px;
      top:0;
    }
```

Is it possible?

The final outcome should be both parent menu and child menu to be on the same line horizontal

Look what i did so far: http://jsfiddle.net/cqfwj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I think I can offer a solution (though I'm sure there are others out there).

I would just play with the position attribute of the elements involved, using relative and absolute positioning.

The style definitions I added/modified in your CSS are as follows:

```
ul{
    position:relative;
}

li ul{
    margin-left:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

Here's the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqfwj/9/) to show you what this results in.

This should give you the behaviour you're looking for. If it's not, then please let me know, and I'll be happy to help further. Good luck!